# python psutil process.io_counters: updates to write_bytes and write_count seem out of synch

Tags: python, psutil

I have a function

```
 def get_writes(process):
   io_counters = process.io_counters()
   return io_counters.write_bytes,io_counters.write_count
```

I expect that if there is an update to write_count that there must be an update to write_bytes. My assumption being that write_count tracks the number of times some bytes are written and write_bytes shows the number of bytes that have been written by the process.

But I'm seeing increments to write_count while write_bytes is static.

So there is an error in my assumptions. Where?

Comment: It's not impossible for there to be writes of 0 bytes.  That's how one truncates a file, for example.  It's also possible that these statistics are not synchronized.  You should treat these as approximations.